# What did I do wrong when I push database registers to Json-server to users.json. I have 404 not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, json-server

I am new to ReactJs coding, I have watched some videos about fake JSON-Server, but I don't know how to post all data from register.js to my "users.json" through "server.js".

What I do is I have an edit "package.json" "script": "auth": "node server.js" and  npm i json-server, npm i json-server jsonwebtoken body-parser --save-dew and npm run auth to run server.js
I learn this on youtube...

Here is my source code. Someone can fix my wrong "post", Thank you!

users.json

```
{
    "users": [
      { 
        "id": 1 
        "username":"admin",
        "email": "123@gmail.com",
        "phone": "01234",
        "pass": "admin1234",
        "gender":"female",
        "role":"shop"
      }
    ]
  }
```

server.js

```
const fs = require("fs"); 
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const jsonServer = require("json-server");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");


const server = jsonServer.create();
const userdb = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./database/users.json", "utf-8"));
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(jsonServer.defaults());

const SECRET_KEY = "85423112"; //*random key to see access-token
const expiresIn = "1h";

function createToken(payload) {
    return jwt.sign(payload, SECRET_KEY, {expiresIn});
}
function isLoginAuthenticated({username, password}) {
    return (
        userdb.users.findIndex((user) => user.username === username && user.pass === password) !== -1 
    ); ư
}
function isSignupAuthenticated({username}) {
    return (
        userdb.users.findIndex((user) => user.username === username ) !== -1);}
   
server.post("api/auth/register", (req,res)=>{
    const {username,email,phone,password, gender,role} = req.body;
    if(isSignupAuthenticated({username})){
        const status = 401;
        const message = "Username already taken";
        res.status(status).json({status,message}) //*taken err will appeare in web console
        return;
    }

    fs.readFile(".database/users.json", (err, data) => {
        if(err){
             const status = 401;
             const message = "err"; 
             res.status(status).json({status,message}) //*err when read file in system will appeare in web console
             return;
        }
         data = JSON.parser(data.toString()); 
        let last_item_id = data.users[data.user.length - 1].id;

        data.users.push({id: last_item_id +1, username:username,email:email,phone: phone, pass:password,  gender:gender, role:role });
        let writeData = fs.writeFile("./database/users.json", JSON.stringify(data), (err, result)=>{
            if (err) {
                const status = 401;
                const message = "err"; 
                res.status(status).json({status,message}) 
                return;
            }
        });
    });
    const access_token = createToken({username,password});
    res.status(200).json({access_token}); //* set status to be OKKKKK when create account success =)))
});

   server.post("/api/auth/login", (req,res)=>{
    const {username,password} = req.body;
    if(!isLoginAuthenticated({username,password})){
        const status = 401;
        const message = "Incorrect Username or Password";
        res.status(status).json({status,message}) //*wrong will appeare in web console
        return;
   }
   const access_token = createToken({username,password});
   res.status(200).json({access_token}); //* set status to be OKKK when login ok =)))
 });
 server.listen(5001, ()=>{
     console.log("running json api server");
 });
```

Register.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import '../styles/Signup.css'
import axiox from "axios";
import {useHistory, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import VisibilityIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Visibility'
import VisibilityOffIcon from '@mui/icons-material/VisibilityOff'
function Register() {
  const [username,setUsername]= useState("");
  const [password,setPassword]= useState("");
  const [email,setEmail]= useState("");
  const [phone,setPhone]= useState("");
  const [gender,setGender]= useState("");
  const [role,setRole]= useState("");
  const [error, setError]= useState("");  
  let history = useHistory();


  const [showPass,setshowPass]= useState(false);    
  const [showconfirmPass,setshowconfirmPass]= useState(false);    

const register = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  axiox.post("http://localhost:5001/api/auth/register", 
  {username,
  email,
  phone,
  password,
  gender,
  role,

    }).then((response)=> {
      console.log("response", response)
      localStorage.setItem("login", JSON.stringify({
     userLogin: true,
      token: response.data.access_token,
      }));
    setError("");
    setUsername("");
    setEmail("");
    setPhone("");
    setPassword("");
    setGender();
    setRole();
     history.push("/login");
    }).catch(error =>setError(error.response.data.message));
  };
    return (
       <div>
         <div id="getstarted">Get started</div>
<div id="intro"><span>Sign up</span> to our website and start to explore your unique style today !</div>
<div class="center">
      <form onSubmit={register}>
  
        <div class="txt_field">
          <input type="text" required
           value={username} 
           onChange={(e)=> setUsername(e.target.value)}/>
          <span></span>
          <label>Username</label>
        </div>
        
          <div class="txt_field">
          <input type="text" required
          value={email} 
          onChange={(e)=> setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
          <span></span>
          <label>Email</label>
        </div>
          
          <div class="txt_field">
          <input type="text" required
          value={phone} 
          onChange={(e)=> setPhone(e.target.value)}/>
          <span></span>
          <label>Phone number</label>
        </div>
          
        <div class="txt_field">
          <input type={showPass ?"text":"password" }required
          value={password} 
          onChange={(e)=> setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
          <span></span>
          <label>Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="password1" onClick={()=>{if(showPass == true){setshowPass(false)}else {setshowPass(true)}}}> 
                 {showPass ? <VisibilityIcon/> : <VisibilityOffIcon/>}
        </div>
          <div class="txtfield_1">
          <input type={showconfirmPass ?"text":"password" } required/>
          <span></span>
          <label>Confirm Password</label>  
        </div>
        <div class="confirm"  onClick={()=>{if(showconfirmPass == true){setshowconfirmPass(false)}else {setshowconfirmPass(true)}}}> 
                 {showconfirmPass ? <VisibilityIcon/> : <VisibilityOffIcon/>}

          {error && <p2 style={{
          color:"red",
           position:"absolute",
           top:"580px", width:"500px", left:"15vw"
           }}>{error}</p2>}

        </div>
          <div id="general">
          <div class="signup_link">
          Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Sign in</Link>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Learn More"/>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <div id="rightside">
    <div id="sex">Sex</div>
    <div id="button">

        <input type="radio" name="gender" value={gender =="male"} onChange={(e)=> setGender(e.target.value)}/>
        <label for="male"></label>
        <span>Male</span>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value={gender =="female"} onChange={(e)=> setGender(e.target.value)}/>
        <label for="female"></label>
        <span>Female</span>
    </div>
    <div class="rect1">
      <button class="button" type="button" value={role == "shop"} onChange={(e)=> setRole(e.target.value)}><img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `/Images/shop 1.png`} /></button>
    </div>
    <div class="rect2">
      <button class="button" type="button" value={ role == "customer"} onChange={(e)=> setRole(e.target.value)}> <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `/Images/take-away.png`} /></button>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
    }
export default Register
```

Comment: try to change `server.post("/api/auth/register", (req,res)=>`

Comment: It works to running and checking new account, it's become 200 OK now. But still do not post the user data to user, may I wrong with declaring "  role", "gender"," email" , " phone" or anything here.

Comment: try to update this line `fs.readFile("./database/users.json"`

Comment: I have some syntax error like   "data = JSON.parse(data.toString()); " and "[data.users.length - 1].id;", I fix it already but     
 data.users.push({id: last_item_id +1, username:username,email:email,phone: phone, pass:password,  gender:gender, role:role });
ReferenceError: email is not defined
this come up
                                                                      ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your route from `server.post("api/auth/register", (req,res)=>{` to `server.post("/api/auth/register", (req,res)=>{` in **server.js** file

Comment: It works to running and checking new account, it's become 200 OK now. But still do not post the user data to user, may I wrong  with declaring anything here..